# The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: php, sql-server

```
$query = "SELECT cc.countryCode, m.stfMode 
          FROM test t LEFT JOIN countryCode cc ON t.idcountryCode=cc.idcountryCode LEFT JOIN mode m ON t.idmode=m.idmode 
          WHERE t.idtest=".$idtest;
```

When i am executing the above query I am getting the below error

> Warning: mssql_query(): message: The multi-part identifier
>   ".countryCode" could not be bound.

Please help....

Comment: Do you mean cc.idcountryCode?

Comment: Looks like you're selecting the table name instead of a column

Comment: Could you show the table structure of the tables, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select cc.idcountryCode`  instead of `SELECT cc.countryCode`

Answer (score 0):

In your Query  `countryCode` is Used for both Tablename and a Column in that table. Please change the tablename or that ColumnName of `countryCode` Table

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL should look like below

```
SELECT 
cc.idcountryCode, m.stfMode 
FROM test t 
LEFT JOIN countryCode cc 
ON t.idcountryCode=cc.idcountryCode 
LEFT JOIN mode m ON t.idmode=m.idmode 

WHERE t.idtest
```